# Search Firebase by a child value (Name), populate a list of matching names and add intent to that list

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to search my Database for a particular pub in my Firebase, and if this pub exists I want to retrieve all data attached to this and display it on my listview. So in the below example if the user types: "This is our pub name" I would like all of the data below added to a list of 'Drinks' (The data class is called 'Drink').

Here is the Database structure:

```
{"Drinks" : {

"-L_JfWQv7xMQfXUvtFhH" : {

  "comment" : "This is my test comment. ",
  "location" : "This is our location.",
  "price" : "This is our price",
  "pub" : "This is our pub name.",
  "rating" : "This is our rating",
  "signature" : "This is my signature"
}
```

Once that search result is displayed in the listview I'd like to be able to click on the search result, and display the values stored in that Drink record on the list.

I hope I've explained this better than my original question.

The code I'll show is my attempt at manipulating the current function I have to retrieve all records in the db.

```
public void searchDB(){

    String searchedString = searchText.toString();



    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Query searchRef = rootRef.child("Drinks").orderByChild("pub").equalTo(searchedString);
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                CapDrink drink = ds.getValue(CapDrink.class);

                drinkList.add(drink);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    searchRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);



    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Search.this, DrinkIndexed.class);
            i.putExtra("ValueKey", drinkList.get(position).getPub());
            i.putExtra("ValueKey2", drinkList.get(position).getLocation());
            i.putExtra("ValueKey3", drinkList.get(position).getPrice());
            i.putExtra("ValueKey4", drinkList.get(position).getRating());
            i.putExtra("ValueKey5", drinkList.get(position).getComment());
            i.putExtra("ValueKey6", drinkList.get(position).getSignature());

            startActivity(i);


        }
    });
}
```

I expect the user to be able to enter a name in the 'searchText' textview, and for that value to be passed into the DB query and then for the query to return the matching Entity

Comment: Please edit your question to include the JSON at `Drinks` (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). It would also be useful if you reduce the scope of your question: if you're having trouble building the correct query, it doesn't matter that you're trying to put the data in a list view and you should be able to reproduce the problem with a simple log statement (and much less code).

Comment: Please add what Frank van Puffelen asked for and please also responde with @

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen

I have updated the question above, thanks.

Comment: @AlexMamo The above has been updated

Comment: The code looks like it matches the data. If you run the code in a debugger, does and place a breakpoint in your `onDataChange`, does it get hit? If so, does it go into the for loop too? If not: can you reproduce the problem with a hard-coded search string: `.equalTo("This is our pub name.")`?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently my issue was with ridiculously bad Android Studio & not my code. For anyone referencing this issue in the future this code will query your Firebase database, display a matching recording in a listview and make the record on that listview clickable(i.e. there's an intent on it and you can do whatever you'd like from that):

```
public void searchDB(){

    drinkList.clear();

    String Pub = searchText.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query searchRef = rootRef.child("Drinks").orderByChild("pub").equalTo(Pub);


    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    CapDrink drink = ds.getValue(CapDrink.class);
                    drinkList.add(drink);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There's been an error, apologies.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };
    searchRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Search.this, DrinkIndexed.class);
            i.putExtra("ValueKey", drinkList.get(position).getPub());
            i.putExtra("ValueKey2", drinkList.get(position).getLocation());
            i.putExtra("ValueKey3", drinkList.get(position).getPrice());
            i.putExtra("ValueKey4", drinkList.get(position).getRating());
            i.putExtra("ValueKey5", drinkList.get(position).getComment());
            i.putExtra("ValueKey6", drinkList.get(position).getSignature());

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for everyones time & effort!